# Mongo search query .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Suppose i have the following variables:
string SKU, string Purchase, string Slider, string Category

.. and the "ID" field in Mongo must contain string value in SKU or if its null or empty, it does not apply.
.. Field "URL" in Mongo must contain string value in Purchase or if its null or empty, it does not apply.
.. Field "Refer" in Mongo must contain string value in Slider or if its null or empty, it does not apply.
.. Field "Category" must contain string value in Category or if its null or empty, it does not apply.

i finally need the count of number of findings.

how do i construct the query in .net?

Comment: How do you construct the query in JSON?

Comment: not in JSON but in c#. i am trying to gather information in c# by connecting to mongo.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question is: do you know how to execute this query in JSON? Then translate that JSON to C#, either using BsonDocuments or using the builder syntax.

Comment: db.page.find( {
    $and : [
        { "URL" : /Confirm/ },
 { "Referrer" : /Purchase/},
 { "Category" : /carpenter/}
    ]
} )

i could do something like this but how do i execute in .net?

Comment: with the official driver most people run Linq queries so no need to translate Mongo queries but it is possible if you want

Comment: @ArjunKP, have you achieved what you wanted?

Comment: no not yet... still searching for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FilterDefinition<TDocument>` or `FilterDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>`

See: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/definitions/#filters

Answer (score 0):

Create empty filter and then use logical and operator `&=` for concatenating filter conditions (if a and b and c...).

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Record>("MyCollection");

FilterDefinition<Record> filter = Builders<Record>.Filter.Empty;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(skuValue)) filter &= Builders<Record>.Filter.Eq(r => r.ID, skuValue);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(purchaseValue)) filter &= Builders<Record>.Filter.Eq(r => r.URL, purchaseValue);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sliderValue)) filter &= Builders<Record>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Refer, sliderValue);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryValue)) filter &= Builders<Record>.Filter.Eq(r => r.Category, categoryValue);
```

For applying filter and retrieving records try this:

```
var documents = collection.Find<Record>(filter).ToList();
foreach (var document in documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ID);
}
```

And this is my Record class.

```
public class Record
{
    [BsonId]    
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string URL {get; set;}
    public string Refer {get; set;}
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the fields must *contain* the string values, I assume you want to apply `.Contains()` not check for string equality.
The following should work, as well as being case-insensitive.

With `collection` as your `IMongoCollection<Record>`, and strongly typed `Record` as in derloopkat's answer:

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sku))
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.ID.ToLower().Contains(sku));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(purchase))
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.URL.ToLower().Contains(purchase));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slider))
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.Refer.ToLower().Contains(slider));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.Category.ToLower().Contains(category));
}

// Commented out, since you mentioned you only want the count
// var results = query.ToList();

var count = query.Count();
```

Another option, if you want to extend this filtering support dynamically...

```
public static class MongoExtensions
{
    public static IMongoQueryable<T> Filter<T>(
        this IMongoQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> field,
        string searchValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
        {
            return query;
        }

        var rx = new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(searchValue), "i");
        var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Regex(field, rx);
        return query.Where(_ => filter.Inject());
    }

    public static IMongoQueryable<T> Filter<T>(
        this IMongoQueryable<T> query,
        string field,
        string searchValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
        {
            return query;
        }

        var rx = new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(searchValue), "i");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex(field, rx);
        return query.Where(_ => filter.Inject());
    }
}
```

```
var query = collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Filter("ID", sku) // Refer to the field with a string...
    .Filter("URL", purchase)
    .Filter(r => r.Refer, slider) // ... or use a lambda expression
    .Filter(r => r.Category, category);

var count = query.Count();
```